# Firing event doesn't work on SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: vb.net, events, radcombobox, addhandler

My webpage is built dynamically in VB.Net (aspx).

I have a checkbox, that after checked will open a new window. While opening the window some parameters are passed through for using the correct data in the window, however there is one parameter (FM) which has an unknown value at the time the checkbox is checked.

This parameter is dependant on a value inside another dynamically built control named ddlFM (radcombobox). For passing this last parameter I will be using a session parameter. This parameter on his turn should be filled when one of the radcomboboxes changes it's value.

In the build function I created the following: (edited)

```
Dim ddlFM As New RadComboBox
Dim sdsFM As New SqlDataSource()

ddlFM.DataTextField = "Value"
ddlFM.DataValueField = "Value"

cell.Controls.Add(ddlFM)
AddHandler ddlFM.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Me.ddlFM_SelectionChanged
cell.Controls.Add(sdsFM)

sdsFM.SelectCommand = 'select values from table'
sdsFM.SelectCommand = 'Connectionstring'
sdsFM.DataBind()
```

the Me.ddlFM_SelectionChanged will be as follows:

```
Public Sub ddlFM_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    getAllCycleNumbers()
End Sub
```

here the getAllCycleNumbers makes sure the correct session id's are filled in.

My problem here is that the event doesn't seem to be fired...

EDIT:

After a post of Murray (which then dissappeared) i added the following line

```
Friend WithEvents ddlFM As RadComboBox
```

This however did nothing...

Comment: Edited for adding the friend with events code...

Comment: Are you sure you are rebinding the event handler when creating the controls dynamically.

Comment: Parintosh, i edited that part, maybe i'm missing something, what always can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help if you do it like this?

```
AddHandler ddlFM.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ddlFM_SelectionChanged)
```

do you also maybe need

```
ddlFM.AutoPostBack = True
```

Comment: when the autopostback is placed, the code passes the eventhandler, on the other hand, all data that was created before the autopostback is deleted

Comment: @Schuere
I think i know what you mean. When the page is posted back the page load event is fired before the postback. You'll need to handle the content you don't want to be refreshed to default using If page.ispostback = true